# Django Form - Select dropdown

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

> How do I Output both "id_no" and "name" [id_no - name] combined in
> dropdown select form. Can it be done directly to the form using
> {{form}} only.

```
Model:
class Employee(models.Model):
  id_no = models.CharField(unique = True,max_length=6)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

Form:
class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
   model = Employee
   fields = __all__
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it be done directly to the form using {{form}} implementing [**str**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#str) :

```py
class Employee(models.Model):
    id_no = models.CharField(unique = True,max_length=6)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id_no} - {self.name}"
```

But not on `EmployeeForm` because this form doesn't have a drop down to pick an employee. You will see it on a modelFrom for a form with a ForeignKey to employee.